# Dynamic table datastructure amortized analysis

Tags: algorithm

Prove that for a dynamic table if the size is increased every time from n to n + √ n when its capacity is reached is Θ (n^3/2) where n is the number of elements? How to approach such problems? Forming an equation using aggregate analysis is complex

Answer (score -1):

A dynamic table of this construction is Θ(sqrt(n)).

Most (sqrt(n) per cycle) pushes take Θ(1) constant time. The last push per cycle takes Θ(n) time to reallocate. Because `sqrt(n)+1=Θ(sqrt(n))` operations have occurred in this cycle, the amortized cost is `( sqrt(n)Θ(1) + Θ(n) ) / Θ(sqrt(n)) = Θ(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: The ask is Θ (n^3/2) and Θ (n^1/2)

Comment: @SaurabhNainwal But Θ (n^3/2) is not possible for a dynamic table, no? Even if you reallocated on every insertion, the time complexity only goes up to Θ(n).